# Problema com operador not na condição de um loop while

Tags: python, while

Fiz um programa para treinar manipulação de txt:

```
def escreve():
    BancodeDados = open("Base.txt", "a")
    continua=True
    k=1
    while continua:
        nome = input("Nome do cliente: ")
        idade = input("Idade do cliente: ")
        while True:
            try:
                sexo = input("Sexo do cliente (m/f): ")
                if sexo == "m" or sexo == "f":
                    break
                else:
                    raise SexoInvalido
            except SexoInvalido:
                print(SexoInvalido())
        BancodeDados.write("Cliente {} Nome {} Idade {} Sexo {}\n".format(k, nome, idade, sexo))
        k += 1
        sessão = 0
        while not sessão == "1" or not sessão == "2":
            sessão = input("Deseja encerrar sessão (1) ou continuar (2)? ")
            if sessão != "1" or sessão != "2":
                sessão = input("Resposta inválida. Deseja encerrar sessão (1) ou continuar (2)? ")
        if sessão == "2":
            continua = True
        elif sessão == "1":
            continua = False
            print("Fechando banco de dados.")
            BancodeDados.close()
```

Gostaria de entender por que apesar da minha condição estar especificada no `while` (linha 20: `while not sessão == "1" or not sessão == "2":`, isto é, enquanto não for inputado 1 ou 2) eu continuo caindo neste laço mesmo quando inputo 1 ou 2 quando essa deveria ser a condição de saída do laço.

Comment: A sua condição é "não igual a 1 ou não igual a 2", que poderia ser traduzida para "diferente de 1 ou diferente de 2"; quando você indica o valor 1 será diferente de 2; quando você indica o valor 2 será diferente de 1. Talvez você devesse alterar para `and`. Aliás, isso você poderia notar fazendo o teste de mesa, recomendo fazê-lo sempre que possuir um problema assim.

Answer (score 3):

O problema está neste `if`:

```
if sessão != "1" or sessão != "2":
```

A condição `or` significa que se qualquer uma das opções for válida, ele entra no `if`. Então se você digitar "2", a condição `sessão != "1"` é válida e ele entra no `if`. Se quer que entre neste `if` somente se as duas condições forem verdadeiras (se `sessão` for diferente de `"1"` **e** de `"2"`), então você deve usar `and` no lugar de `or` ([documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)).

A condição deste `while` também tem esse problema, mas você também poderia fazer assim:

```
while True:
    nome = input("Nome do cliente: ")
    idade = input("Idade do cliente: ")
    while True:
        sexo = input("Sexo do cliente (m/f): ")
        if sexo == "m" or sexo == "f":
            break
        else:
            print('sexo inválido')

    BancodeDados.write("Cliente {} Nome {} Idade {} Sexo {}\n".format(k, nome, idade, sexo))
    k += 1
    while True:
        sessão = input("Deseja encerrar sessão (1) ou continuar (2)? ")
        if sessão != "1" and sessão != "2":
            print("Resposta inválida", end=" ") # só imprime a mensagem
        else:
            break

    if sessão == "1":
        print("Fechando banco de dados.")
        BancodeDados.close()
        break
```

Se `sessão` não for `"1"` nem `"2"`, eu só imprimo a mensagem indicando que ela é inválida. Não precisa usar `input` dentro do `if`, pois a próxima iteração do `while` já fará isso (eu só coloquei um `end=" "` no `print` para que depois da mensagem seja impresso um espaço em vez da quebra de linha, assim a mensagem "Deseja encerrar sessão..." ficará na mesma linha, como você pretendia fazer no seu código).

Repare no uso de `break` para interromper o loop. E cada `break` refere-se ao loop em que se encontra: o primeiro dentro de `if sexo == "m" or sexo == "f"` interrompe o loop que faz a leitura do `sexo`, o segundo dentro do `else` interrompe o loop que lê a `sessão`, e o terceiro dentro do `if sessão == "1"` interrompe o loop principal (repare que por causa disso, nem precisa da variável `continua`).

Os `if`'s também poderiam ser trocados para `if sexo in ("m", "f")` (se o `sexo` for `"m"` ou `"f"`) e `if sessão not in ("1", "2")` (se `sessão` não é `"1"` nem `"2"`).

Também removi o `raise SexoInvalido`, eu preferi imprimir a mensagem diretamente quando o `sexo` não for `"m"` nem `"f"`.

---

Conforme o programa cresce, esse monte de `while`'s dentro de outro pode acabar deixando o código confuso. Se quiser, pode quebrá-lo em funções menores, ex:

```
def ler_sexo():
    while True:
        sexo = input("Sexo do cliente (m/f): ")
        if sexo in ("m", "f"):
            return sexo
        else:
            print('sexo inválido')

def ler_opcao():
    while True:
        opcao = input("Deseja encerrar sessão (1) ou continuar (2)? ")
        if opcao not in ("1", "2"):
            print("Resposta inválida", end=" ")
        else:
            return opcao

BancodeDados = open("Base.txt", "a")
k=1
while True:
    nome = input("Nome do cliente: ")
    idade = input("Idade do cliente: ")
    sexo = ler_sexo()
    BancodeDados.write("Cliente {} Nome {} Idade {} Sexo {}\n".format(k, nome, idade, sexo))
    k += 1
    if ler_opcao() == "1": # a opção nem precisa de variável, pode comparar direto
        print("Fechando banco de dados.")
        BancodeDados.close()
        break
```

Agora nos loops que fazem a leitura do `sexo` e da opção para continuar eu coloco `return` em vez de `break`, assim a função só retorna o valor se ele for uma das opções válidas (se não for, pede que o usuário digite novamente).

No final, eu fiz `if ler_opcao() == "1"`: o resultado de `ler_opcao()` não precisa de uma variável, eu posso comparar o seu retorno diretamente com `"1"`. E nem preciso verificar se é `"2"` para saber de devo continuar o loop, pois a função `ler_opcao` já garante que só será retornado `"1"` ou `"2"`.